# Get count of contacts with email addresses that matches other contacts in same tables

Tags: mysql, query

I have a contacts table that is like this:

```
|id|first_name|last_name|date_entered|
```

then, I have a table that stores the email addresses like this:

```
|id|email_address|
```

I then have a relational table that joins the two tables above together like this:

```
|id|contact_id|email_id|
```

What I am trying to figure out is, how do I get a count of all new contacts that has been entered in between 2023-02-10 and 2023-02-13  but *only* the contacts that have matching emails?

For example, a new contact is entered in the db with the email of test@123.com. A few days later, that same contact comes back and is entered in by another person but with the same email address of test@123.com.

I am building a report of "New vs Returning Customers" and we use their email to identify a customer that is returning. So, I am needing to be able to list a count of all customers in the database with the same email that is > 1. Is this possible with MySQL? Thanks!

Comment: Please consider following [these suggestions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql/2977#2977).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what I left out? I thought I was being fairly thorough with my question. But, I edited a couple of mistakes I noticed above just in case. Thank you for the feedback.

Comment: Your question arguably addresses the first point from the linked post, but not points 2, 3, and 6. If you make it easier for people to reproduce your data and _see_ the results you expect, it will also make it easier for them to post a good answer.

Comment: The title sounds like you need a "self join".

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this

```
SELECT C.first_name,C.last_name,CE.contact_id,E.email_address
FROM contacts_emails CE
INNER contacts C ON CE.contact_id = C.id
INNER JOIN emails E ON CE.email_id = E.id
WHERE C.date_entered >= '2023-02-10 00:00:00'
AND   C.date_entered <= '2023-02-13 23:59:59';
```

Now to identify new verses returning

```
SELECT
    C.first_name
   ,C.last_name
   ,CE.contact_id
   ,E.email_address
   ,IF(EC.emailcnt=1,'New','Returning') NewOrReturning
FROM contacts_emails CE
INNER contacts C ON CE.contact_id = C.id
INNER JOIN emails E ON CE.email_id = E.id
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT email_address,COUNT(1) emailcnt
    FROM emails GROUP BY email_address
) EC ON E.email_address = EC.email_address
WHERE C.date_entered >= '2023-02-10 00:00:00'
AND   C.date_entered <= '2023-02-13 23:59:59';
```

This is just a start. Hope this helps.

Comment: This is great! This got me "super" close. I just had to change up the subquery. But, I am having two issues with this:

1. It is very, very slow to run for some reason. Not sure if there is a way to speed it up?
2. it is not giving me the "Returning" count that I needed. It does list all of the new and returning. But, I was needing the counts of new vs returning. Any suggestions?

Comment: Here is the updated query I have (with the leads table):  

    `SELECT
    l.first_name
   ,l.last_name
   ,e.email_address
   ,IF(EC.emailcnt>1,'Returning','New') NewOrReturning
FROM leads l
INNER JOIN email_addr_bean_rel er ON er.bean_id = l.id
INNER JOIN email_addresses e ON er.email_address_id = e.id
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT email_address_id,COUNT(1) emailcnt
    FROM email_addr_bean_rel GROUP BY email_address_id
) EC ON e.id = EC.email_address_id
where l.date_entered >= '2023-02-12 06:00:00' 
 AND l.date_entered < '2023-02-13 19:38:56'
and l.deleted = '0';`

Comment: Do you have an index on the `date_entered` column in the `contacts` table ??? If you don't, then index it with `ALTER TABLE contacts ADD INDEX idx_date_entered (date_entered);`

Comment: Yes, I have an index on that table for date_entered.

Comment: any thoughts or suggestions on how to get the count for new and returning instead of just returning the entire list? Here is the SQL statement that is working that you provided (it is just listing everything instead of showing the count). Thanks so much for you help!

Comment: SQL statement: 

`SELECT    
 l.first_name    ,l.last_name    ,e.email_address
    ,IF(EC.emailcnt>1,'Returning','New') NewOrReturning 
FROM leads l 
INNER JOIN email_addr_bean_rel er ON er.bean_id = l.id 
INNER JOIN email_addresses e ON er.email_address_id = e.id 
INNER JOIN (     SELECT email_address_id,COUNT(1) emailcnt     
    FROM email_addr_bean_rel 
GROUP BY email_address_id ) EC ON e.id = EC.email_address_id 
where l.date_entered >= '2023-02-12 06:00:00'   
AND l.date_entered < '2023-02-13 19:38:56' 
and l.deleted = '0';`